# Modify gamma of a PNG image without modifying pixels

Tags: imagemagick

How to do the following "conversion"?

**Input:**

A PNG image which claims it is encoded in sRGB, but in-fact is linear

**Output:**

A PNG image with the same pixel values the input, but instead tagged as linear

This sort of works (colors are corrected in the output image):

```bash
convert -verbose -set colorspace RGB test_pattern_raw.png -depth 16 PNG64:test_pattern.png
```

but

```
$ identify test_pattern.png 
test_pattern.png PNG 1600x1000 1600x1000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 78821B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

It should say RGB not sRGB.

I also tried to go through EXR (which by definition is linear), but ImageMagick insists on saving PNG:s in sRGB.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "linear"? I am not aware of such colour space.

Comment: Intended intensity proportional to pixel values

Comment: Do you know what the profile should be? Linear profiles tend to be very much device-specific. In photoshop [or probably any other half decent graphics package] you can simply assign a new profile. No conversion takes place, the image is just interpreted differently to screen. Tony Kuyper has kindly provided a huge number for download - https://goodlight.us/linear-profiles.html

Comment: @Tetsujin With linear I think of pixels as intensity values. The device that renders these pixels may or may not be linear, but that is irrelevant. In my case the "device" is most likely some kind of rendering software. For the primaries and all that stuff that goes into colors, I assume D65 as standard illuminant.

Comment: lin or log, they're both 'intensity values'. You just need to know how to map them. That's what profiles do. You have one for your image & one for your computer display & your computer's colour-match engine does the rest. You can actually assign any profile you want, if you like the results. Are you certain this should be linear? Are you sure it's not just a gamma issue caused by it coming from a Rec 709 or similar?

Comment: Didn't I say *lin*ear? `-set colorspace RGB` before the input file makes `convert` treat the input as if it were linear (thus it ignores any metadata in the input file). Verified by looking at the resulting image. That is what I want in this case. Now I want it to skip gamma conversion, so the output file is also linear.

Comment: I know you said linear, but as you don't seem to quite know how this all works, I thought I'd try get closer to ground zero. Having a copy of the image might help, but as it stands I can't figure out just what or why you want what you seem to want. "…so the output file is also linear" doesn't really make any sense. You assign a profile to do that, as I said right at the start. That's what they're for.

Comment: Did you try `"-colorspace RGB"` rather than `"-set colorspace RGB"` ?

Comment: @Perm This modifies the input pixels, which should not happen.

Comment: In Post, you say "colors are corrected in the output image" in working case : Does this mean the input pixels are changed ? Or unchanged ?

Comment: When replying to my last query about input pixels changing or not changing, you should use "@Prem" , otherwise I will not be notified even when there is a typo like "@Perm". I would encourage you to try `"-colorspace RGB"` which may or may not resolve your issue but that will give Data Points to Debug this Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I have found a bug in ImageMagick, with the fix https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/commit/59953e741c004f84b4a164d430a1be5ca3db2d44